# Align buttons to the bottom of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, uielement

i want to align two buttons to the bottom of the screen as follows. i tried the xml given in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272106/align-button-to-the-bottom-of-screen) but no luck.how to do it ?

like this -

[image]

this should be without the spacing in the bottom

[image]

Comment: Try out the answer below and let us know if it helped.. :)

Comment: Normally, the answer given in link and below mentioned answer would work. If that doesn't work, you should have something different. Post your XML.

Comment: guys look like its not buttons they've used..i saw this in a app and i wanted to adopt it to my app.

Comment: The answer by aashima solves your problem correctly. It must be accepted

Comment: i already accepted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the property you need to use:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Try using the following XML and customize your button appearance as you like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d1000000"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="PREV"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want to add these buttons to the bottom of the screen without spacing..in your xml there is a space.

Comment: Check my edited answer above. It should solve your problem.. :)

Comment: thanks for your effort..but the spacing is still there..i edited the question refer the figures.i think its not buttons i need.trying out imageviews instead.

Comment: Thats quite simple.. Just remove the padding given to the RelativeLayout. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The same works with ImageView. You just need to replace `Button` by `ImageView` in my answer and add the `android:src` property

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the reputation necessary to comment on the response aashima

but I think you also have to add `android:weightSum="2"`

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="PREV"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="NEXT"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an invisible variable to initialize the others on the layout .

For example, create an ImageView and make it invisible . After this center it vertically . You can also choose the height to match parent . So in the middle of the screen (vertically) there will be an ImageView . You can also set the width to 0,1 or more it depends on what you want and what kind of images you have

After you create it , for 'Previous' button you can choose AlignLeft option and choose this ImageView . For 'Next' button you can choose AlignRight and show this ImageView again .

With this trick the buttons always will be mirrored to each other on the screen .

Answer (score -2):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="before"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/i"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="after"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```