# Need help aligning buttons to bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, layout

Here is what it looks like currently:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaBpP.png

I want buttons to go and align at bottom (and cover all screen from sides too). I try to do this but getting unexpected results. Here is layout code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="238dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="271dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_row="2" />
    </GridLayout>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide"
            style="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: which button you want at bottom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: @Mahesh Suthar, Last row, and all other rows just above it, hence move all buttons to bottom. Tried to do it in graphical interface but it doesn't allows me to move.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478856/align-buttons-to-the-bottom-of-the-layout/31478974#31478974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to make the Numbers Grid covering the side spaces and the bottom space.Checkout if it is required o/p.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000" >

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="238dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_row="2" />
</GridLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/grid"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/divide"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/multiply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/minus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="."
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equals"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="="
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: Calc image]

Comment: Thanks @prashant, that is helpful, can you explain your changes?

Comment: Yes @ShahbazTalpur I used relative layout as the root layout. It allows to easily align it's child's at bottom of the page using the align parent bottom attribute. And I enclosed the rows in table view and set it's gravity for child to bottom. You can upvote the answer if it worked 

Comment: Yeah I up voted, but its not publicly visible as I have low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I add some sample code. Try to use this. It is just sample code....

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Home" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="7"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/div"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="/" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mul"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="*" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sub"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="c" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```